# How do I open a command file in a different Terminal window?

Tags: macos, shell, scripting

I am trying to make a shell script that opens a command file. The code I'm using is simple.

```
open -e file.command
```

All it returns in the Terminal window is:

```
logout

[Process completed]
```

Is there any way I can open this shell file in a different Terminal window?

Comment: what is the command file supposed to do? the `-e` option tells terminal to open whatever it is in `TextEdit`.

Comment: Okay, this helped. I used open -a instead of open -e. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-e` option opens your command in `TextEdit`

```
   open -a file.command
```

`-a` application
         Specifies the application to use for opening the file

Comment: Yes, I figured this out, thanks. Also, to add to your answer, the complete code I used was `open -a Terminal.app file.command`